# Remove lines from image background

Tags: html, css, border

I'm not the best in css, but when I have a div with a background image, and I overlay a svg that only has a border, the border lines are shown on some devices. It should look like this.[image: How the content should look]

But when I load this on mobile view, the border lines are shown. How can i fix this?
I've tried to add a padding, and tried to use an backgroud position offset, but that didn't work.

[image: Content with the image borderes]

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-origin: content-box;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Ubuntu;
      overflow: hidden;
      /* Hide scrollbars */
    }

    .container {
      margin: auto;
    }

    .column.left {
      margin: 0;
      float: left;
    }

    .column.right {
      float: right;
    }


    /* Clear floats after the columns */

    .item {
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: left top;
      background-origin: content-box;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      /*border-radius: .9rem .9rem 0 .9rem;*/
    }

    .item h2 {
      font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
      text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, #000000);
      background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 0%, #000000);
      bottom: 0;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: normal;
      left: 0;
      margin: 0;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
    }

    .item1 img,
    .item2 img,
    .item3 img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="overzicht">
            <div class="column left">
                <div class="item item1" style="background-image: url('https://i.regiogroei.cloud/552x310/43692b31-6c5e-3c1c-9734-0fda6b587107.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: center">
                    <img src="./StoreplayNEWS_Tekengebied 1.svg" style="position: absolute; z-index: 5; width: 100%; height:100%" alt="">
                    <h2 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tincidunt sed justo sit amet rhoncus</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column right">
                <div class="item item2" style="background-image: url('https://i.regiogroei.cloud/552x310/13650346-f88e-3b81-b54a-af81dccd4369.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: center">
                    <img src="./StoreplayNEWS_Tekengebied 1.svg" style="position: absolute; z-index: 5; width: 100%; height:100%" alt="">
                    <h2 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tincidunt sed justo sit amet rhoncus</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="item item3" style="background-image: url('https://i.regiogroei.cloud/552x310/ee982215-e923-3ea5-b65f-2230e1d36fad.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: center">
                    <img src="./StoreplayNEWS_Tekengebied 1.svg" style="position: absolute; z-index: 5; width: 100%; height:100%" alt="">
                    <h2 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tincidunt sed justo sit amet rhoncus</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post an [example].

Comment: If you set border-style: none; on your divs/img CSS classes does it still happen?

Comment: @EgilHansen this didn't fix it. It looks like the border is a pixel or two of the background image

Comment: That's really weird! Got me curious... what browser & device are you using?

Comment: @EgilHansen I'm using Windows on Chrome version 100. It's also present on Android with webview version 85. On Firefox I don't see this behaviour

Comment: Ok, found what is causing it, so now i will try to find a solution ;) It's not a border for sure! It's your background images.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer. The problem was that the .item h2's background was overlapping. I've changed that to this and that fixed the problem.

```css
.item h2 {
    font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, #000000);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 0%, #000000);
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 0;
    margin: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the border and outline property to zero on the parent and child elements.

```
{
 border: none;
 outline: none
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately that didn't fix my problem